# How to test $broadcast and $on events in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, event-handling, jasmine

I am trying to test the $broadcast and $on events in Angular.
I have a function that creates a date and does some calculation on it, then send the result to another controller via $broadcast.

What I want to be able to do, is test the $broadcast has happened and also the $on listener to see what the result was.

I can test the former but the latter fails.

I have created a JSFiddle with a basic example of what I am trying to achieve here http://jsfiddle.net/devonCream/zhbjfunm/6/

Works

```
   expect(rootScope.$broadcast).toHaveBeenCalledWith('sendTime',tDate);
});
```

But....

```
    expect(rootScope.$on).toHaveBeenCalledWith('sendTime', Function);
```

Gives

```
     Expected spy $on to have been called with [ 'sendTime', Function ] but actual calls were [ 'sendTime', Function ]
```

which look identical to me!

(for a bonus point, can someone can tell me why my fiddle will not work over https!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of :

```
expect(rootScope.$on).toHaveBeenCalledWith('sendTime', Function);
```

Try :

```
expect(rootScope.$on).toHaveBeenCalledWith('sendTime', jasmine.any(Function));
```

[UPDATE]

working fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/zhbjfunm/10/

```
time = time
```

was the main trouble !

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Boris for your answer, though your solution did make the test work, I didn't complete give me what I needed, but pointed me in the right direction, what I needed to do was to resend the event and pick up the result in the 2nd controller, so.

```
    it('Should have time set on 2nd controllers scope', function () {
        mainScope.sendEvent(); 
        expect(subScope.currentTime).toBe('2015-03-20T10:00:05');
    });
```

Work!

Thank you.